# Data Transformation in Mule ESB

Tags: mule, datamapper

My Mule flow query a Database and inserts the data queried in Salesforce. One of the column in DB has values say 'C','P'&'U' this needs to be inserted into a picklist in Salesforce which has values 'Company', 'Person', 'Unknown' where C should map to Company and P to Person etc. Any pointers on how to do this would be of great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom MEL function and use it in your flow, in an `expression-transformer`:

```
<configuration>
  <expression-language>
    <global-functions>
      def translateType(t) { 
        typeMap = ['C' : 'Company', 'P' : 'Person', 'U' : 'Unknown'];
        typeMap[t];
      }
    </global-functions>
  </expression-language>
</configuration>
```

With this in place, you can use `translateType` in your flows.

Reference: [MEL Global Configuration](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Tips#MuleExpressionLanguageTips-GlobalConfiguration)